# difference between machine bit and php bit

Tags: php, macos, 64-bit, 32-bit, processor

I am using a Machine with processor Core i5 64 bit in Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5.
But when I try to work with integer greater than 32 bit is not working as an integer.

**INPUT**

```
<?php 
var_dump(is_int( 4294967296 ));//2^32
var_dump(is_int( 2147483648 ));//2^31
var_dump(is_int( 2147483647 ));//2^31-1
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

But as my machine is 64bit so I should I not expect that 2^32 will work as an integer?

Is there any setting with PHP?

Or how can I know the machine bit structure using PHP?

Comment: You need 64-bit PHP to work with 64-bit integers in PHP, this isn't a simple setting, it's a different build of PHP.... if you compile PHP from source, then the build will autodetect the machine bitsize and build appropriately; if you download a prebuilt version of PHP, then you need to pick the appropriate build to download

Comment: In my Mac the PHP is in-built and now it seems to be that `The most common use is to select the 32-bit architecture on a 64-bit processor, even if a 64-bit architecture is available.`